# How do I add RADIUS clients to Windows NPS without a known IP or DNS?

Tags: windows, ip, ip-address, radius

When trying to add a RADIUS client to Windows NPS, it REQUIRES an IP address.  What if this IP address is known?  i.e. using cloud based WAPs with WPA Enterprise authentication?  i.e. CloudTrax, Ubiquiti Unifi, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can use CIDR notation when entering the IP address.  However, when you do, all possible IPs in the subnet count towards the 50 count limit on NPS prior to Windows Server 2012.  i.e. 192.168.1.0/24 ... 254 > 50, fail.